# Extracting a particular file from a zipfile using Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 3 million html files in a zipfile. I would like to extract ~4000 html files from the entire list of files. Is there a way to extract a specific file without unzipping the entire zipfile using Python?

Any leads would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit:My bad, I should have elaborated on the question. I have a list of all the html filenames that need to be extracted but they are spread out over 12 zipfiles. How do I iterate through each zipfile, extract the matched html file and get the final list of extracted html files?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj this is not a duplicate. OP wants to extract multiple files without unzipping all the contents.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you wish to extract all the `html` files, then you can this out. If you have the list of all the file names to be extracted, then this will require slight modification.

```
listOfZipFiles = ['sample1.zip', 'sample2.zip', 'sample1.zip',... , 'sample12.zip' ]
fileNamesToBeExtracted = ['file1.html', 'file2.html', ... 'filen.html']
# Create a ZipFile Object and load sample.zip in it
for zipFileName in listOfZipFiles:
    with ZipFile(zipFileName, 'r') as zipObj:
       # Get a list of all archived file names from the zip
       listOfFileNames = zipObj.namelist()
       # Iterate over the file names
       for fileName in listOfFileNames:
           # Check if file to be extracted is present in file names to be extracted
           if fileName in fileNamesToBeExtracted:
               # Extract a single file from zip
               zipObj.extract(fileName)
```

Comment: He said that ALL of the filies are HTML files.  BUT the key for this is answer is the conditional which allows him to define his own results based on the filename.  If he needs to search based on file CONTENTS, it requires a different method.  I still think this is a sound option.  He just doesnt define specific search criteria perse.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response @taurus05. I have updated my question, I do have a list of html files that need to be extracted but they are spread out over 12 zip files, how do I iterate over all the zipfiles and get my extracted html files?

Comment: @AdityaVemuganti i've updated the answer. If anything seems unclear, let me know.

Comment: @AdityaVemuganti If it  works, you can upvote it, so that it can be helpful to others as well.